# Bounded variation problem

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $x=0.a_1a_2\dots$ be the decimal expansion of a number $x$, $0<x<1$. If two decimal expansions of $x$ exist, the one that ends with $0$’s is taken. For what values of $q > 1$ is the function of bounded variation?
\begin{align*}
f_q(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty q^{-k} a_k
\end{align*}

I am not sure how to approach this problem.  I know that if I want to show a function if not of bounded variation I must find an appropriate partition, but I don't know what intuition will help me find one for this function.  I will appreciate any hints.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't $f_q$ non-decreasing? (Honest question, I'm not sure.)

Comment: Are you asking if $f_q(x)$ is non-decreasing in $q$ or in $x$?

Comment: I think he is asking with respect to $x$. It $f(x)$ is non-decreasing, then as long as $f(1)$ is bounded we done since the total variation is just $f(1)-f(0)=f(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $1<q<10$, $f$ is not of bounded variation: observe that $f$ jumps at every $x$ with ambiguous decimal expansion. Say $x=0.a_1\ldots a_{n-1}10000\ldots$. Compare $f(x)$ with $f(y)$, where
$$
y=0.a_1\ldots a_{n-1}099\ldots 9000\ldots ,
$$
with a long string of $9$'s. Then
$$
f(x) - f(y) \to q^{-n}\left( 1 - \frac{9}{q-1} \right)
$$
as we increase the length of this segment. Since there $10^{n-1}$ initial segments $a_1\ldots a_{n-1}$ that can go here, we see that these jumps contribute $\gtrsim (10/q)^n$ to the total variation, and $f\notin BV$.

For $q\ge 10$, $f$ is indeed increasing and thus BV. If $x>y$ and $n$ is the first digit where the decimal expansions of $x,y$ differ, then it suffices to observe that
$$
\sum_{j>n} 9q^{-j} = \frac{9}{q-1} q^{-n} \le q^{-n} .
$$